# Building gtkbuilder file with gtk 3 using python

Tags: python, gtk

I am currently following [this](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-3.html) tutorial.
When I run the according python file I get the same issue as [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2012-June/msg00012.html) (though I use python, not Vala).

So apparently I have to tell python to use gtk3, but how do I do this?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, python2.7, glade3.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's strange. You could use GtkHBox or GtkVBox as a workaround. However, these two have been deprecated recently (in GTK 3.2), in favor of [GtkGrid](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html). Also, you may want to give a look to the official [Python GTK 3 tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

While I don't found the cause of the problem, I got it to work by simply copying the contents of my.glade into another.glade, opened in glade, saved it and run the script on it. I probably made some mistake which I cannot reproduce anymore, oh well.

Thanks though to liberforce, as the tutorial posted gives a better understanding about the "gtk+ side" of the problem, while I only concentrated on glade so far.